# Page url links to pages internal frame

Tags: html, css, google-crawlers

I have a personal website, which I have made (to the best of my ability) without a template. I am not very experience in HTML so am not entirely sure if this is bad practice or not, but here is my issue.

My website consists of a `frameset`, which has 3 frames. Two do not change (banner and nav panel), and the other is content. The way I display my content in the main frame is through an iframe. Here's where the trouble comes. I have suggested my website to the crawler, and it crawls all the pages for content, of course. When I click on one of my links suggested by google (say, a project), the browser loads that individual `.html` file, without any of the rest of my frames. In other words, it does not link to the page through my `index.html` which sets up the formatting and page frames, but simply loads the html as a stand-alone page.

Is there a way I can avoid this, so that if a link for my website is clicked from an external link (not from my domain), the page first loads my `index.html`, and then the page of interest, so that it appears as if it were accessed normally from my index? I am not sure whether I should find a new way of displaying my content in the main frame so that it avoids iframes, or just need a simple script to redirect the user.

Not sure if it's useful but I've attached a photo of my page just to better explain what the frame layout is that I am working with.

Many thanks!!!

[image: Website Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iFrames are definitely not the route to take when you are displaying consistent content... Which from what appears to be the Navigation, Header, and of course, the Content. Of course there will be an issue when a "Search Engine Spider" crawls your page... From my understanding, seeing as you are calling "content" from another page, the spider will crawl that page but will not crawl the index.html page we are currently viewing. When a "Spider" crawls a page it looks for STATIC HTML Tags/Content/Keywords/etc, and seeing as you are calling all of your content from other pages the "Spider" will treat that content as being on another page as well.

You want me recommendation? Avoid using an iFrame at all times. The point of an iFrame is to display content from another location (external), and or display static content on a page without having to scroll the current page you are viewing the iFrame on.

It is bad practice to use an iFrame, I would suggest using DIVs. Within these DIVs you may place content, images, links... Virtually anything you want, with all of the benefits of having people view your website, along with Search Engine Spiders.

I hope this helps!
Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: With just using `div`s, am I able to still cycle content similarly to how I have now, with `.html` files for each page? Or should I, in each page, set up the `frameset` to contain the nav bars, banner, etc?

Comment: @iKiar: Why would you need to use iFrames for the Navigation and Banner? Are you trying to use the iFrames as "Includes" Files? So you do not have to repeat the Navigation and Banner statically throughout every page? If that is the case, I would suggest looking into a Server-Side Includes, like PHP.

Comment: I don't use iframes for the banner, they're just part of a frameset, to as you say statically display them throughout every page. I will look into PHP, but for the mean time I think will take your initial suggestion and just include the content in a `div`. Thanks!

Comment: @iKiar: You will not be able to cycle content through your pages. A DIV allows you to "contain" your content in a sense. You need to learn more about CSS, to accomplish what I think you're trying to accomplish in the sense of style. Using iFrames are no longer a standard really. Just enter your content in Statically. Within the HTML of the index.html file. Do not use iFrames to embed content within your page, all it will do is bog down the experience for the end-user, yourself, and it will create more of a hassle than just having the content withtin the index.html statically. No iFrames.

Comment: Thanks, I will set up everything statically and eventually (when time is in excess) learn how to use server-side includes with my banner and nav system. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @iKair: If you are interested in learning more of a difference between DIVS and iFrames... Visit this: http://www.designerstalk.com/forums/web-design/2826-iframes-vs-divs.html . If you are interested in learning more about PHP Includes, read this: http://www.stevedawson.com/article0012.php

Remember to mark as Answer if you feel as if your question has been completed.

Comment: @iKair: You are very welcome, just a tip. A lot of people that do not know PHP and or use PHP on a regular basis still use PHP Includes... Just so they do not have to keep repeating their content that is going to be consistent throughout their website... Hence a Navigation bar and or Banner.

Comment: I did, don't worry! ;) And I feel comfortable with the differences between Divs and iFrames, just wasn't sure if I was missing a chunk of information.

Answer (score -1):

iFrames are a bad choice. AJAX is VERY simple these days. Just replace the big iFrame with a Div, and AJAX a page, putting the contents into that Div.

Replace your anchors with  tags, and replace href with name, like so:

```
<div name='main.html' class='link' />
```

You need a div with the id 'loadHere': 
Then include jQuery (it's pretty easy, google it) and at the end of your HTML put this:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    $.post(this.name,function(dat){
        $('#loadHere').html(dat); }); });
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on that? How would I place an AJAX page inside of the div, and then by use of my links, target the AJAX page to display my other `.html` pages.